# Reverse of Convert.toString(b,2)

Tags: c#, binary, stringbuilder

```
 byte[] fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes("D:\\a.txt");
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (byte b in fileBytes)
        {
            sb.Append(Convert.ToString(b, 2).PadLeft(8, '0'));
        }
```

after these steps I want to get filebytes from sb.
thanks in advance.

PS: what i am trying to do is convert a file to 0s and 1s and then convert it back to that file

Comment: So you're converting a string of bytes to a long string of `0` and `1` characters and want to convert it back to bytes?

Comment: The inverse of `Convert.ToString(byte, int)` is [`Convert.ToByte(string, int)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7xhf79k(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: The reverse of `Convert.ToString(byte,int)` is `Convert.ToByte(string,int)` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7xhf79k(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can:

```
byte[] buff = new byte[sbText.Length / 8];
for (var i = 0; i < sbText.Length / 8; i++)
    buff[i] = Convert.ToByte(sbText.Substring(i * 8, 8), 2);
```